# Explanation and validation of point adding/doubling on elliptic curves

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, elliptic-curves

I'd like to implement point multiplication on elliptic curves over prime fields. 
My problem is that I've found different definition how to do it.

At adding: the second parameter of the result is not tha same on [WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Point_addition) and on [WolframMathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticCurve.html). Why are the different? I think it's simple but I don't get it.

And a side-question: what is the simplest way to check my results? I've found a few calculator applet, but they give different results, so I can't say which one is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wikipedia entry is correct.  The sum of two points is supposed to be the *reflection* across the $x$-axis of the third point of intersection of $E$ with the line through $P$ and $Q$.  The equation of the line through $P$ and $Q$ is $y = \lambda (x - x_1) + y_1$.  So we need to plug in $x_3$ and then take the negative, giving $$y_3 = \lambda(x_1 - x_3) - y_1.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't think it is a typo. One says lambda(x_3-x_1)+y_1, other says lambda(x_1-x_3)-y_1 , which is -1 times the first one. No typo or double typo.

Comment: @gkovacs90 Oh you're right, didn't read carefully enough.  Still only one of them can be correct, but both points are on the curve.  I changed the answer now.